# Checkboxes and multiple file download on submit?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, download

I need to create a form to download selected files. Basically, on `submit`, I need to check which checkboxes are checked and then download the corresponding files. I have no idea where to start, and I need to be able to do it in Javascript or JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It will need some steps to accomplish your task.

First you need to create a form with multiple checkbox, something like below form:

```js
$('#submit').click(function() {
  
  $('#test').submit();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="test" name='test' action="process.php" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="downloadone"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="downloadtwo"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="downloadthree"><br>
<button id="submit" type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Second in your process.php file get the form values and extract the download info.

Third do the downloading based on download info. The simplest way is using php coding.

Don't forget to sanitize your form for more security.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was hoping it could have been done without PHP, as I am still fairly weak on that end. But I've also searched for an answer for two days and no.

Comment: @BenSmiles There's some good library out there. Such as  [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html) . Try to take a look.